# Add trailing slash to url using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, trailing-slash

I would like to add trailing slash for deep level of my urls

So let's say i have this url

> mysite.com/work

when user access that url, i want to be redirected to:

> mysite.com/work/ (this i want to happen)

But i want this only deep levels, not for .html pages

> mysite.com/testing.html/ (i don't want this to happen)

I have this .htaccess rule, but this add trailing slash to my .html pages also. i don't want that.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule for adding trailing slash only for non-files:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)[^/][?\s]
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: It's still adding trailing slash to my html files.
e.g test.html/ i want only for paths or folders